# Wordpress meta box values display to custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added meta boxes to my posts using the action "`add_meta_boxes`" to add/change custom settings like background-color, etc.

When I enable the custom fields in my screen options, all values of my meta boxes are displayd in these custom fields!

There are also showing up in the selectbox to add a new "custom field".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide your post meta data from custom fields metabox, you should start your meta keys with underscore. Example `_background-color`

Added:

Also you can use `is_protected_meta` filter, which return boolean value (`true - hide, false - show`).

Filter parameters: `$protected, $meta_key`. See `wp-includes/meta.php` file. function `is_protected_meta()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This seams to work.
But is there no other possibility for that issue?

I saw themes, where there don't use "is_protected_meta" or underscore for the keys, and the meta data doesn't show up at the custom fields.

Comment: I don't know any other possibility, except these two. I also quickly looked through wordpress source, that renders "Custom Fields" metabox, and didn't find any additional possibilities. You can try to use wordpress options instead post meta, but it strongly not recommended. I really don't know how it may be implemented in such themes without these possibilities, need to see theme code =)

Comment: This helped me, thanks! FYI to others using OOP/Class, you can put `add_filter('is_protected_meta', array($this, 'my_is_protected_meta',), 20, 2);` at the bottom of your constructor. Check out [multi-post-thumbnails](https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails) for a nice example. (**Don't miss this part:** To unhide meta from the Custom Fields metabox, add `add_filter('mpt_unprotect_meta', '__return_true');` to your theme's `functions.php`.) Nice feature. :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally WP hides meta keys that start with an underscore/`_` from the *Custom Fields* (default/core) MetaBox.

Now imagine that you do not want to give the user of your plugin the possibility to alter Post Meta Data through the ugly and user unfriendly Custom Fields meta box. And therefore you build a custom meta box and prefix your meta key with an underscore/`_`. Then the user changes his mind and deactivates or uninstalls your plugin. What happens now is that the user has exactly **no access to any UI** to alter the (still present) meta data. This is a really, really bad situation for the user.

So we need a *switch* to turn off the *Custom Fields MetaBox* access **as long as your plugin is activated**. Therefore WP Core got the `is_protected_meta()` function. It basically consists out of two lines of code:

```
$protected = ( '_' == $meta_key[0] );
return apply_filters( 'is_protected_meta', $protected, $meta_key, $meta_type );
```

As it's not nice to only offer a filter to handle that, WordPress today has a simple function that you can use:

```
register_meta( $meta_type, $key, $sanitize_callback, $auth_callback );
```

And the last argument, the `$auth_callback` does the following inside this function:

```
if ( empty( $auth_callback ) ) {
    if ( is_protected_meta( $meta_key, $meta_type ) )
        $auth_callback = '__return_false';
    else
        $auth_callback = '__return_true';
}

if ( is_callable( $auth_callback ) )
    add_filter( "auth_{$meta_type}_meta_{$meta_key}", $auth_callback, 10, 6 );
```

As you can see, you want to just add `'__return_false'` as `$auth_callback` to **deactivate Custom Fields MetaBox access** as long as your plugin is active. When the user removes or deactivates your plugin, he instantly has access to the meta field via the standard *Custom Fields MetaBox*.

---

Notes: WP core at v4.0.1 while writing this question. Make use of the `$sanitize_callback`! Thanks to Trepmal for posting about the `is_protected_meta` filter on her blog. Else I would have never stumbled upon the use case for that.