# How do I overwrite WordPress core functions?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first time touching WordPress, and I have the task of extracting the core functions that have been customized and putting them in a non-core file so that it's more maintainable when we upgrade. Here's an example of one of the methods in `wp-admin/includes/template.php` :

Original code:

```
    function meta_form() {
        global $wpdb;
        $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
        $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
            SELECT meta_key
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            GROUP BY meta_key
            HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
            ORDER BY meta_key
            LIMIT $limit" );
        if ( $keys )
            natcasesort($keys);
    ?>
```

Customized version:

```
function meta_form() {
    global $wpdb;

  if ( isset($_GET['post']) )
    $post_id = (int) $_GET['post'];
  elseif ( isset($_POST['post_ID']) )
    $post_id = (int) $_POST['post_ID'];
  else
    $post_id = 0;

  if ( $post_id ) {
    $post_ = get_post($post_id);

  }

  if ($post_->post_type == 'video_photo' ){
    $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
    $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT meta_key
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    where meta_key like 'tqmcf_%'
        GROUP BY meta_key
        HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
        ORDER BY meta_key
        LIMIT $limit" );
  }else{
    $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
    $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT meta_key
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta

        GROUP BY meta_key
        HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
        ORDER BY meta_key
        LIMIT $limit" );
  }

    if ( $keys )
        natcasesort($keys);
?>
```

Where exactly would I define my `meta_form()` function to make sure it overwrites the core method?

Comment: If you simply want to hide some meta keys in certain cases, you might be able to hook a filter onto `is_protected_meta`. [This answer may also be relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9431938/1321716)

Comment: That method was just an example of a ton of methods that were changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In WordPress you can't owerride the whole core. You have two ways to modify the WordPress Core :

### First option : Pluggable functions

Some functions can be redefined. This can be done in theme's `functions.php` file or in a plugin file. You can check the list of the [Pluggable Functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions).

### Second option : Filter and Action hooks

- [Filter hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) can be used to modify vars inside the core
  WordPress process.
- [Action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) can be used to fire custom
  function on some events.

Notice 1 : you can create your own filter and action hooks in your theme or plugin.

Notice 2 : you can use filter hooks to fire a function if you don't find a convenient action hook.

If you follow the WordPress coding standards, you should be able to deeply modify the behaviour of WordPress.

For the function your showing, you should look for the [post_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter hook, to do something like this :

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'my_posts_where' );

function my_posts_where( $where ) {

    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'video_photo' ){
        $where .= " AND meta_key like 'tqmcf_%'";
    }

    return $where;
}
```

**Edit 1:** The following may be more suitable even if this specific query is hard to target.

```
add_filter( 'query' , 'my_meta_form_query' );

function my_meta_form_query( $query ) {

    $pattern = "/SELECT(?:\W*)meta_key(?:\W*)FROM (.*)(?:\W*.*?)*LIMIT(?:\W*)([0-9]*)/g";

    if( preg_match($pattern, $query, $vars) ) {
        $postmeta = $vars[1];
        $limit = $vars[2];

        $query = "SELECT meta_key
                FROM $postmeta
                WHERE meta_key like 'tqmcf_%'
                GROUP BY meta_key
                HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
                ORDER BY meta_key
                LIMIT $limit";
    }

    return $query;
}
```

You have to digg into the code to find suitable hooks and how you can best filter variables. In this example, we check if the query is matching the one in the `meta_form()` function. We extract the existing query vars and we build a new query including the `WHERE` condition. I didn't test this piece of code and there may be some bugs but it can give you an idea of how we alter the core code.

Comment: hey strategio, how would I test this code? I'm not sure where I can actually see the effects of the original source code. I want to test before and after to see if it functions the same

Answer (score 6):

There's no ***replacing core functions***, unless they're defined in [`wp-includes/pluggable.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php).

You can modify values and processes [using hooks](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/) where available (you'll find them mainly by `apply_filters` and `do_action` functions in core files). IMO, there are more specialists and knowledge base at [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), but I suggest focusing on the end result because you could hook on the `wpdb` or the `postmeta` queries, for example.
In you sample code, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but the only filter hook available doesn't seem adequate, hence the need of other hook and clear objective.

In the end of the day, the proper way of modifying WordPress behavior is through the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the WP function you want to replace, put something like this in your theme's functions.php file:

```
function my_new_function () {
/* Your replacement code.... */
}

remove_filter (the_content, old_wp_function);
add_filter (the_content, my_new_function);
```

Where 'the_content' is the post's entire content - so you could use this, for example, to replace Wordpress's wptexturize() function (which changes, among other things, ordinary quotes to 'smart' quotes) with your own.  [Or, if you simply don't want to use the WP function at all, just use the remove_filter statement above.]

Answer (score -1):

Why not just edit the core file and just add if(!function_exists...)
then copy and edit the functions into you funcitons.php file.

Then when you upgrade you will receive errors of all the functions that are declared twice but will be easy enough to go and ad if(!function_exists...)

Comment: Maintenance nightmare

Comment: we can't edit the core file because when we update wordpress  your changes will be loss.so we have to only override in function.php file using add_filter Hooks.

Comment: I understand your guys concern but in certain cases where you cannot use filters and hooks and the core function is not pluggable you may have to write your own code and use your own functions however depending on the clients budget and other concerns my answer above does work.

So if rewriting the desired functionality is more work than the client can afford, rarely it may make sense to copy the core function into your theme, make the changes you want, and then edit the core file and simply wrap the function with if(!function_exists...). On theme updates yes you will receive an error.

Comment: I support Allon here. Unless someone explains why WP makes lots of essential function non-overridable. See wp-includes/theme.php. Why don't those functions have if(!function_exists...) in the first place? Hooks are often just overkill/way too complicated for simple small changes.

Comment: also, someone looking to actually edit the core file, wrapping core function in function_exists won't work as it is loaded before theme functions. You would have to comment out the core function. Then simply comment out the function again after every update. It sounds like a nightmare but it's pretty simple.