# Wordpress plugin that overrides function in wp-includes file

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first time attempting to make a Wordpress plugin. I would like to insert three lines of code into the `post-template.php` file under `wp-includes`. I am thinking I will need a way to override the function, in this case, `get_the_content`, so that it calls my plugin's version of the function instead of the default one.

Based on what I've searched, it is not a good idea to override the core files so I'm hoping there is a simple way to modify the function through my plugin.

What would be the best method to go about doing so?

Comment: You're out of luck, there's no filter available for this function. I tracked the other functions that it uses but also no entry point...

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite it using the same function name inside your plugin, also you could create a child theme and inside that you can copy the file post-template.php so it will load the edited version instead without updating issues, or it may be possible (if its plugable) to overwrite or edit it using a hook, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202451/7862006

Answer (score 0):

You got that right. Never modify the core files directly for [these reasons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files). However, luckily there are different ways to achieve what you want in WordPress. The simplest would be to add a filter in `functions.php` (if you are using a theme find the functions.php inside `../themes/..`) like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'new_content_filter');
function new_content_filter( $content )
{
    $new_content = 'hello';
    return $new_content;
}
```

This will get the content and apply a new filter on it.

Comment: He's asking about `get_the_content` (called by `the_content`).

Comment: I got that, but I supposed at the end he/she wants to apply some filters on the content.