# How to modify the built-in wp_trim_words function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm sending text content to the wp_trim_words function from a PODS magic tag but the default word limit is too long. I'd like to build a function to shorten the default word limit of wp_trim_words.

PODS is sending the content just fine, but the output isn't what I want. I'd like to have a limit of 15 words instead of the default 55.

I've tried to hack together a little function to modify the output of wp_trim_words, but I can't get it to work.

I know there are ways of doing this by putting wp_trim_words into the PHP template directly, but that doesn't work for me as I'm using a PODS template.

What I've got so far for my function is:

```
function mylength( $num_words ) {
return 15;
}
add_filter( 'wp_trim_words', 'mylength' );
```

"Obviously" it's just outputting the number "15". And I can SEE why that's happening, but I'm just stuck on how to tell the function that I want the $num_words to be set to 15.

I also tried:

```
function mylength( $num_words ) {
$num_words = 15;
}
add_filter( 'wp_trim_words', 'mylength' );
```

And this just produces nothing.

Any help greatly appreciated and apologies for the noobiness.

Comment: I believe that this answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202529/401499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in function for that: wp_trim_words().

```
function mylength( $title )

{
    // limit your words
    return wp_trim_words( $title, 15, '' );
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'mylength' );
```

You can put any kind of limit on almost anything you like

```
    function mylength($title) {
    $len = 5; //change this to the number of words
    if (str_word_count($title) > $len) {
        $keys = array_keys(str_word_count($title, 2));
        $title = substr($title, 0, $keys[$len]);
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'mylength');
```

Comment: Looks exactly what I need, thank you Amit. I'll try it later today and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use it

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 15 ); ?>
```

Example title="`<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 15 ); ?>`"

Comment: Hi Amit and thank you for your help! It doesn't help though I'm afraid. I'm not using a regular template with PHP so I have nowhere useful to put it. That's why I'm trying to put this inside a function in wp functions.